# How to find maxium value from nested array Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to find biggest value for particular array objects from nested array.

My Javascript Array:

```
const Application = [
  {
    chartData: [
      {
        title: "Type 1",
        value: 60,
      },
      {
        title: "Type 2",
        value: 21,
      },
      {
        title: "Type 3",
        value: 4,
      },
    ],
    name: "App 1",
  },
  {
    chartData: [
      {
        title: "Type 1",
        value: 34,
      },
      {
        title: "Type 2",
        value: 45,
      },
      {
        title: "Type 3",
        value: 8,
      },
    ],
    name: "App 2",
  },
  {
    chartData: [
      {
        title: "Type 1",
        value: 59,
      },
      {
        title: "Type 2",
        value: 1,
      },
      {
        title: "Type 3",
        value: 3,
      },
    ],
    name: "App 3",
  },
];
```

I want to find the maximum value of the nested chartData array.

I want a method to calculate the maximum value and for the above data the output should be 60.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about using `.flatMap` and `.sort`?

Comment: You should have tried something and then add a question here. There will be a lot of questions related to it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this way:

```
const maxValue = Math.max.apply(
  Math,
  ...Application.map((e) => {
    return e.chartData.map((el) => {
      return el.value
    })
  })
) //[60,21,4,34,45,8,59,1,3]
console.log(maxValue) //60
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just browse trough it, like you would with any other 2d Object-Array. You have 2 for loops. One loops trought Application itself, another loops trough chartData. The code looks as follows:

```
let maxVal = 0
for (let i = 0; i < Application.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < Application[i].chartData.length; j++) {
    if (Application[i].chartData[j].value > maxVal) {
      maxVal = Application[i].chartData[j].value
    }
  }
}
console.log(maxVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the combination of `flatMap` along with `Math.max` to get the maximum value.`flatMap` flattens the array to a depth of 1, and then use `Math.max` to get the maximum value out of it.

```js
const Application = [ { chartData: [ { title: "Type 1", value: 60, }, { title: "Type 2", value: 21, }, { title: "Type 3", value: 4, }, ], name: "App 1", }, { chartData: [ { title: "Type 1", value: 34, }, { title: "Type 2", value: 45, }, { title: "Type 3", value: 8, }, ], name: "App 2", }, { chartData: [ { title: "Type 1", value: 59, }, { title: "Type 2", value: 1, }, { title: "Type 3", value: 3, }, ], name: "App 3", }, ]
const result = Math.max(
  ...Application.flatMap(({ chartData }) => chartData.map(({ value }) => value))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What about using `flatMap`?

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your array of values and use `Math.max()` to find out the maximum value.

```js
const application = [ { chartData: [ { title: "Type 1", value: 60, }, { title: "Type 2", value: 21, }, { title: "Type 3", value: 4, }, ], name: "App 1", }, { chartData: [ { title: "Type 1", value: 34, }, { title: "Type 2", value: 45, }, { title: "Type 3", value: 8, }, ], name: "App 2", }, { chartData: [ { title: "Type 1", value: 59, }, { title: "Type 2", value: 1, }, { title: "Type 3", value: 3, }, ], name: "App 3", }, ],
      maximum = Math.max(...application.flatMap(({chartData}) => chartData)
                          .map(({value}) => value));
console.log(maximum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution, it can be done some improvements, hope it helps you

```js
import {reduce } from 'ramda'

const maxValue = reduce((max, {value}) => value > max ? value : max, -Infinity)
const maximunValue = reduce((acc, {chartData}) => maxValue(chartData) > acc ? maxValue(chartData) : acc, -Infinity)

maximunValue(Application) // function returns 60
```

The solution in ramda documentation [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20Application%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20chartData%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%201%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%2060%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%202%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%2021%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%203%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22App%201%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20chartData%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%201%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%2034%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%202%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%2045%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%203%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%208%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22App%202%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20chartData%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%201%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%2059%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%202%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3A%20%22Type%203%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22App%203%22%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0Aconst%20maxValue%20%3D%20reduce%28%28max%2C%20%7Bvalue%7D%29%3D%3Evalue%3Emax%3Fvalue%3Amax%2C%20-Infinity%29%0Aconst%20maxValueChartData%20%3D%20reduce%28%28acc%2C%20%7BchartData%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20maxValue%28chartData%29%20%3E%20acc%20%3F%20maxValue%28chartData%29%20%3A%20acc%2C%20-Infinity%29%0AmaxValueChartData%28Application%29)